# Django - Update multiple models from one view (form-table)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have this three classes

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Input(models.Model):
    idProduct   = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField()
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Output(models.Model):
    idProduct   = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField()
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And I whant to make a view/form with a table like this

```
| output-quantity->product  | product-name | input-quantity->product |
```

List all Product from DB and add the quantity for each product (input or output)

Following that I sum up input and output and then subtract them to have a stock record for each product.

**My problem is I do not understand how I can use three models simultaneously in views / forms**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your view code.

Comment: you can , can you plz share your views here

Comment: I do not know how to do it.
I did not find an example on the net where to use multiple models in the same view

Answer (score 0):

To access the models in the view all you must do is import them like this (provided you have followed the Django structure): `from .models import Product, Input, Output`. You can now access the models.

Now use functions such as `Products.objects.all()` to get the data you want, for instance that command will return ALL Product objects saved in your database. For more info on Django Queries read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Thank you for the input
I think I'm understanding now


`select product.name,
SUM(input.quantity) - SUM(output.quantity) as Stock
from product
 join input ON (product.id=input.idProduct)
 join output ON (product.id=output.idProduct)
group by product.name
order by product.name`


I have to translate this sql to django orm.
Minor problems understanding:  select_related, annotate, aggregate

Comment: I think you can get where you want with basic filter and get statements, try to break the SQL down into chunks to make it easier to approach. Select_related prepopulates any foreign keys so it doesn't have to re-query when trying to access them, giving a performance boost.